# SuperSU vs Root

Tags: rooting, root-access, superuser

I have seen two methods, which claim that they root an Android device, that I don't know the difference of.
Method 1 is as easy as installing the SuperSU from Google Play.
Method 2 is going downloading some files, going to recovery mode by pushing some complex buttons simultaneously, and much more difficult stuff. (e.g. [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2139263))

What is the difference? Does Rooting in both methods mean the same thing? If yes, why should anyone bother himself trying the second method?

Regards

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just installing SuperSU don't give you root - it's only *tool for controlling access* to root account on rooted device.

From app's description:

> SuperSU requires a rooted device !!!

Answer (score 5):

When coming from Linux/Unix, you may be confused because su == root, and that is also true on Android, but with a small addition:

A 'rooted' android device has a setuid root 'su' binary to allow a process to get root, but the version typically used on android doesn't allow just any process to use it to get root. It uses an android intent to communicate with an app (superuser/supersu) to determine if the caller is allowed to get root. The app then decides if it's allowed, typically with a popup on the screen of the android device.

More details here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13138867/how-does-android-superuser-app-detect-that-an-app-requests-root